# Installing spacy locally

Tags: python, spacy, python-module

I installed `spacy` locally like this:

`pip3.7 install --install-option="--prefix=/proj/aa/myusername/lib/python" -U spacy`

Local installation completed successfully.
Now when I tried to download English package

`python3.7 -m spacy download en`

It gave me an error like this:
`No module named spacy`

So I did:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH /proj/aa/myusername/lib/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages 
python3.7 -m spacy download en
```

It seems to download everything correctly but last step failed when it tried to write to an area which needs admin privileges:

```
creating /admin_access_path/.package/python-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/en_core_web_sm
error: could not create '/admin_access_path/.package/python-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/en_core_web_sm': Read-only file system
```

How do I prevent this and do the download locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past the issue by adding `--install-option`

```
python3.7 -m spacy download en --install-option="--prefix=/proj/aa/myusername/lib/python"
```